Orient a texture in a consistent manner, without relying on UV unwrapping
Without using UV wrapping, and only relying on shader nodes, is there any way to orient the shingles as indicated on the image before?
I'm looking to not use UV wrapping as this roof geometry is parametric and the angles and outline change consistently change throughout the design iteration. I'm using the https://bonsaibim.org/ plugin.
The following example file has both a procedural material and traditional texture based material : https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/5gi7c1h7dzu3948alpfm2/shingles-roof-direction.blend?rlkey=0sgmyad8526lmb4m5ivsgosj3&dl=1


It is, thank you!  For those passing by here's the updated file.
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/5gi7c1h7dzu3948alpfm2/shingles-roof-direction.blend?rlkey=0sgmyad8526lmb4m5ivsgosj3&st=xuhhs7ky&dl=0
